# Is there a framework to abstract authentication in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I want to make a web application where authentication method is completely configurable (it may be openid, it may be windows authentication, it may be anything else).

I would prefer just changing a single setting in web.config to get a different auth solution. The application needs a `Principal`/`Identity` with some kind of user name (some other user details can be good, but not required at this point).

Is there any good framework that can help me or should I build my own?

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with the built in [ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx) feature? It can be used with ASP.NET MVC or WebForms. You can plug in other providers as needed. There is an OpenID provider that's available on [CodePlex](http://openidmembership.codeplex.com/) - although I haven't used it.

Comment: Yes, I know about it, however it provides only a simplest part -- models, while I am interested in complete solution. Also last time I used it I remember bumping in API problems. But I'll look at it once more, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the best approach. That's how I implemented OpenID - combining DotNetOpenAuth with ASP.NET Membership is very simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Ryan's answer: You can create a class which inherits from `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider` (located in the System.Web.ApplicationServices library in MVC3). To configure which provider to use you need to provide entries in your Web.config like the following:

```
<!-- In configuration -> system.web -->
<membership defaultProvider="ServicesMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="ServicesMembershipProvider"
         type="APISite.Infrastructure.Web.Membership.ServicesMembershipProvider"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="false"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

You can have multiple providers defined in this section and set the `defaultprovider` to the one you want to use at the time.